# Convert SQL to Linq select in where

Tags: sql, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I have three table below:

```
TABLE_PRODUCT (IdProduct, ProductName, ProductUnit) 
TABLE_STORE_HOUSE (IdContain, IdProduct, ProductNumber, TimeInput) 
TABLE_SELL (IdSell, IdContain, ProductNumberSell, TimeSell)
```

Current, How to using LinQ query get `TABLE_STORE_HOUSE.IdProduct` witch condition `TABLE_STORE_HOUSE.ProductNumber - Sum(TABLE_SELL.ProductNumberSell) > 0` and `TABLE_STORE_HOUSE.TimeInput` is smallest

Help me convert Sql to Linq..............

```
select top 1 IdContain 
from 
    TABLE_STORE_HOUSE 
where IdProduct = '6' 
      and 
        ProductNumber - (select sum(ProductNumber) 
                         from TABLE_SELL 
                         Where TABLE_SELL.IdContain = IdContain)> 0 
order by TimeInput desc;
```

Comment: What's your exact problem? Do you have trouble with specific LINQ syntax elements?

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I have 1 segment problems like. But i don't know how to convert to linq syntax

Comment: Please never just post SQL and ask for conversion. At least show a class model so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible. Also, tell what type of LINQ you're targeting (to entities?), and show your own first efforts so we see where *specifically* you need help.

Comment: Sorry, I have described below

Comment: Please do not post additional info as an answer - [edit] your question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
from t in TABLE_STORE_HOUSEs 
let TSell =  (
                from s in TABLE_SELLs 
                where s.IdContain == t.IdContain
                orderby s.ProductNumber
                select new { 
                         s.ProductNumber
                        }
               )
where t.IdProduct == 6 && (t.ProductNumber - TSell.Sum(si => si.ProductNumber)) > 0
select new { t.IdContain }
```

for top 1 you can use `Take()` function.